# Backing up Datastore through Cronjob

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So this is the native cronjob entry to backup a datastore

```
cron:
- description: My Daily Backup
  url: /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&kind=LogTitle&kind=EventLog&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=whitsend
  schedule: every 12 hours
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

If I have a `kind` with spaces, how would I do that in this? So if my kind was "Log Title" would I do like `kind=Log%20Title`?

Regardless of whether it has spaces or not, this doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone know what else I'd have to do to make sure it back ups?

I don't see it in my `ah-builtin-python-bundle` logs in [admin.appengine.google.com](http://admin.appengine.google.com).

It also appears that I can't manually backup anymore since when I click Datastore Admin, it leads me to a page with no content. ([Google Bug Report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11848&thanks=11848&ts=1427987922))

Any help would be appreciated. PS. I am using PHP App Engine.

Comment: about the Datastore Admin not working... I found the same issue while using Chrome, but it works for me in Firefox

Comment: @marianosimone Ah thanks, I'll try Firefox. Used to only not work in Safari, now it doesn't work in Safari or Chrome. I got past it by copying and pasting the link from the console error.

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest as a quick fix you escape the ampersands (&) with HTML encoding `&amp;`

so you would have:

```
cron:
- description: My Daily Backup
  url: /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&amp;kind=LogTitle&amp;kind=EventLog&amp;filesystem=gs&amp;gs_bucket_name=whitsend
  schedule: every 12 hours
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

But that URL cannot exceed 402 chars, so a better solution is to write your own servlet to handle the backup by automatically adding the various entity kinds. I know you're running a PHP backend, but here's an example in XML and Java from my code.

**cron definition in cron.xml**

```
<cron>
    <description>Daily backups New Way</description>
    <url>/cron/backups</url>
    <schedule>every day 06:00</schedule>
    <timezone>America/Los_Angeles</timezone>
</cron>
```

**url mapping in web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BackupServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.your.package.BackupServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BackupServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cron/backups</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**backup task in queue.xml**

```
<queue>
   <name>backup-queue</name>
   <rate>25/s</rate>
   <bucket-size>25</bucket-size>
   <max-concurrent-requests>25</max-concurrent-requests>
</queue>
```

**servlet class BackupServlet.java**

```
public class BackupServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("backup-queue");
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BackupServlet.class.getName());

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        List<String> entities = DatastoreUtils.getEntityList();

        // Print query results
        for (String kind : entities) {
            log.info("Creating backup task for " + kind);
            queue.add(withUrl("/_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create").param("name", "datastore-backup-" + kind + "-").param("kind", kind)
                    .param("filesystem", "gs").param("gs_bucket_name", ADMIN_BACKUPS_BUCKET));

        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

    }
}
```

**and finally getEntityList() in DatastoreUtils.java**

```
public static List<String> getEntityList() {
    List<String> rc = new ArrayList<String>(50);

    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    // Start with unrestricted kind query
    Query q = new Query(Entities.KIND_METADATA_KIND);

    List<Filter> subFils = new ArrayList<Filter>();

    // Limit to lowercase initial letters
    subFils.add(new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, Entities.createKindKey("A")));

    String endChar = Character.toString('Z'); // Character after 'z'

    subFils.add(new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, Query.FilterOperator.LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, Entities.createKindKey(endChar)));

    q.setFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.and(subFils));

    // Print query results
    for (Entity e : ds.prepare(q).asIterable()) {
        rc.add(e.getKey().getName());
    }

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, java is quite confusing to me but I think I get the gist of it. How is the cron bypassing the 402 limit again? Are you making separate backup requests for each entity? Also, if I have spaced in my entity name and I wanted to do it all in that one cronjob, would I do `%20` for a space?

Comment: Hey no problem. You definitely seem to get the gist of it. Correct, the above code makes a separate backup request for each entity, although you could easily combine them into a single call instead by chaining the `.param("kind", kind)` calls (while still automating the entity list generation). Also correct, a URL encoded space should be `%20` ... sorry I don't have a PHP solution, but I hope the Java helps!

Comment: Hi Mr. Kevin Thomas. I tried your suggested method but the cron task keeps failing on a 302 error. Are you setting specific security constraint on the servlet mapping ?

Comment: Now I am able to contact the Cron URL and add a backup task in the push queue. However I am getting 403 when requesting /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create . 
It indeed needs an admin access but in your sample you don't seem to make any authentication. I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly fine for me. Steps to be followed

1. Make sure "Datastore Admin" is enabled in "Built-ins" option in the "Application Settings" menu under "Administration" in left navigation menu in "admin.appengine.google.com".
2. Once you enable datastore admin, go to your "App engine" → "Dashboard" and check if "ah-builtin-python-bundle" is listed under the "Version" drop down box.
3. Upload your cron.yaml file using "appcfg.py update_cron" command
4. Go to the "Cron Jobs" in the left navigation menu and check if the cronjob is listed there as mentioned in cron.yaml

Note:

1. & replacement is not necessary as its required only for Java since it uses xml file. Since you use yaml, amp encoding is not necessary
2. Use the default bucket name fully like "appid.appspot.com", which is mentioned in the "Application settings"

[Official Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups)